# NGINX redirect all subfolder to domain root

Tags: regex, nginx

I need to redirect all subfolders to root domain, eg. www.example.com/* to www.example.com.

I have tried the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://site/;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    location ~ ^/(.*?)/?$ {
        return 301 http://www.example.com;
    }
}
```

But it does not work, I think it gets stuck in a redirect loop.

Comment: what is this question mark doing right before `$` ?  `location ~ ^/(.*?)/?$`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your regex might be incorrect. You can use a site like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bPLcrm/1) to help you with regex.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/IcASRw/1) is an example of a regex expression that will register as truthy for any url that has anything following the `.com` portion of the url:

`\.com\/(?=.+)`